# Why am I getting "run-time error '424': object required" using VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue with some code I'm writing in VBA. I'm getting this error, but I don't think I'm using it wrong, since I wrote something very similar in another sub.

```
Sub quicktest()
Dim testrng As Range
Set testrng = Sheet5.Range("J81")
AddNewRecordsColumn testrng
End Sub

Sub AddNewRecordsColumn(bottomcell As Range)
Dim copyrng, pasterng As Range
Set copyrng = Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Range("E3"), bottomcell)
Set pasterng = Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Range("D3"), bottomcell)
pasterng.Value = copyrange.Value 'this is the line highlighted by debugger

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

On the last line, the one highlighted, copyrange does not exist. copyrng does, small difference.

Comment: Wow, that was dumb, can't believe I missed that! Thanks, every so often I need someone to point out the obvious to me!

Comment: Please flag your question as answered and you will be forgiven for your programming mistake. Tim also made a good suggestion to add Option Explicit.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim copyrng, pasterng As Range
```

Because a data type hasn't been specified for copyrng it is a variant. For Variants use Value2 or make copyrng a range.

From Help for Dim

**type** **Optional**. Data type of the variable; may be Byte, Boolean, Integer, Long, Currency, Single, Double, Decimal (not currently supported), Date, String (for variable-length strings), String * length (for fixed-length strings), Object, Variant, a user-defined type, or an object type. *Use a separate As type clause for each variable you declare*.